# How to split comma separated string of records and arrange then sequentially in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I want to a MySQL query to select the records separately from  following table

```
   ID  AgentID    Name   Return Date
   1   1,2,3       A     2016-05-22,2016-02-1,2016-1-15
   2   2,4         B     2016-03-22,2016-04-1
```

Expecting Answer

```
ID  AgentID    Name   Return Date
1    1          A     2016-05-22
1    2          A     2016-02-1
1    3          A     2016-1-15
2    2          B     2016-03-22
2    4          B     2016-04-1
```

Comment: Please tell us that this is because you've realised a fundamental flaw in your original design,and now want to correct it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX(). It will return the sub-string from the given comma separated string before a specified number of occurrences of the delimiter.

Try this, It seems to work fine:

```
SELECT ID
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.AgentID, ',', n.n), ',', -1) Agent
       ,Name
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.Return_Date, ',', n.n), ',', -1) Return_Date
FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN 
 (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
   FROM 
     (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
   ORDER BY n
  ) n

WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.Return_Date) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.Return_Date, ',', '')))
ORDER BY ID;
```

Check this.. 
<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53133f/4)</kbd>

For further Study go on     [**MySQL Split String Function**](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Answer (score 0):

if your values in tblA and you want to insert into tblB than query like this

```
insert into tblB (date) select date from tblA;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO second_table ( 
      Field_1, 
      Field_2, 
      Field_3) 
SELECT Field_1, 
      Field_2, 
      Field_3 
      FROM first_table;
```